# UITableViewCell multiple select circle (Edit Control) coming randomly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I created a ViewController with a UITableView as a subView.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var tableDataSource = [
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply du.",
        "It is a long established .",
        "Lorem Ipsum come",
        "All the Lorem .",
        "The standard ch.",
        "The generated.",
        "Various versions."
                           ]


    private var isReorderingEnabled = false
    private var isDeleteEnabled = false

    @IBOutlet private var reorderCellsBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet private var selectCellsBarButton: UIBarButtonItem! {
        didSet {
            selectCellsBarButton.tag = ButtonTags.Select
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet private var deleteCellsBarButton: UIBarButtonItem! {
        didSet {
            deleteCellsBarButton.tag = ButtonTags.Delete
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak private var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
        }
    }

}


extension ViewController {

    private struct ButtonTags {
        static let Delete = 2
        static let Select = 1
    }

    private struct LocalizedStrings {
        static let EnableReorderingText = "Reorder"
        static let DisableReorderingText = "Done"
        static let EnableSelectionText = "Select"
        static let ConfirmDeletionText = "Delete"
        static let DisableDeletionText = "Cancel"
    }

}



extension ViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setDeleteBarButton(hidden: true, animated: false)
    }
}



// IBActions
extension ViewController {

    @IBAction private func reorderCells(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        isReorderingEnabled = !tableView.isEditing
        setSelectBarButton(hidden: isReorderingEnabled)
        sender.title = isReorderingEnabled ? LocalizedStrings.DisableReorderingText : LocalizedStrings.EnableReorderingText
        tableView.setEditing(isReorderingEnabled, animated: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction private func deleteCells(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        isDeleteEnabled = !tableView.isEditing
        setDeleteBarButton(hidden: !isDeleteEnabled)
        selectCellsBarButton.title = isDeleteEnabled ? LocalizedStrings.DisableDeletionText : LocalizedStrings.EnableSelectionText
        if sender.tag == ButtonTags.Delete {
            deleteSelectedRows()
        }
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = isDeleteEnabled
        tableView.setEditing(isDeleteEnabled, animated: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

// Custom Helper methods
extension ViewController {

    private func setDeleteBarButton(hidden: Bool, animated: Bool = true) {
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([(hidden ? reorderCellsBarButton : deleteCellsBarButton)], animated: animated)
    }

    private func setSelectBarButton(hidden: Bool, animated: Bool = true) {
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton((hidden ? nil : selectCellsBarButton), animated: animated)
    }

    private func deleteSelectedRows() {
        guard let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { return }
        let indexes = selectedRows.map { $0.row }
        tableDataSource.remove(indexes: indexes)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: selectedRows, with: .fade)
    }

}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableDataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        customCell.setup(content: tableDataSource[indexPath.row], for : indexPath.row)
        return customCell
    }

}


// pragma - To Select/Edit/Move TableView Cells
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableDataSource.move(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
        let reloadingIndexPaths = IndexPath.createForNumbers(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: reloadingIndexPaths, with: .none)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableDataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
    }

}

// pragma - Settings for Edit/Move TableViewCell
extension ViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        print("Edit- \(tableView.isEditing)")
        return tableView.isEditing
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        print("Move- \(isReorderingEnabled)")
        return isReorderingEnabled
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        print("Style- None")
        return .none
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        print("indent- \(isDeleteEnabled)")
        return isDeleteEnabled
    }

}
```

In this, I have made three bar buttons,one for Reordering , and other two for Deletion and Cancellation. 
So, for delete I have provided ability to select multiple rows.

But the problem is, when Reordering selected, the checkbox is still appearing(Not clickable though). And sometimes when Deletion selected, checkbox doesn't appear.

[image: Simulator Snapshot]

**Cannot understand the absurd behaviour. Is this a bug of XCode ? Please help.**

Added Content:

CustomTableViewCell class :

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "customCellIdentifier"

    @IBOutlet weak private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak private var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        let selectionView = UIView()
        selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        selectedBackgroundView = selectionView
    }

}



extension CustomTableViewCell {

    func setup(content: String, for rowNumber: Int) {
        titleLabel.text = content
        let backgroundImageName = rowNumber % 2 == 0 ? ImageAssetNames.BlueMatte : ImageAssetNames.GreenThreads
        backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: backgroundImageName))
    }

}
```

Comment: Tableview is one of the most used ui elements in iOS, so you can be almost certain that it isn't a bug. Since you are configuring your cell in your cell class, you need to show that code.

Comment: without seeing your cell code, my hunch is that you're adding your custom content to cell.view, rather than cell.contentView. By adding it to contentView, it should adjust for the edit controls

Comment: I am actually not doing anything big in the cell class.... Still i have provided now....